# c# this.sightCursor = new Cursor(GetType(), "Sight.Cur") gives Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: object, reference, cursor

```
namespace Sample {
    public partial class Catcher: UserControl {
    Cursor sightCursor;
    bool running = false;
    CWindow parent;
    CWindow curWin = 0;
    Highlighter highlighter;
    public Catcher() {
        InitializeComponent(); * * this.sightCursor = new Cursor(GetType(), "Sight.Cur"); * *
        this.LostFocus += new EventHandler(Catcher_LostFocus);

        if (highlighter == null)
        highlighter = new Highlighter();
        ((CWindow) highlighter.Handle).Transparent = true;
    }


    * * this.sightCursor = new Cursor(GetType(), "Sight.Cur"); * * this is where i get error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object!

    Sight.Cur is available at my recources also!

    Looking forward of your helps..Thanks
```